# Return row when SUM(column) = value, on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sum

My table:

```
id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT
date date
number int(3)

+----+------------+--------+
| id | date       | number |
+----+------------+--------+    
| 1  | 2010-01-02 |   0    |
| 2  | 2010-01-03 |   3    |
| 3  | 2010-01-04 |   0    |
| 4  | 2010-01-05 |   2    |
| 5  | 2010-01-06 |   1    |
| 6  | 2010-01-07 |   3    |
+----+------------+--------+
```

I would like return the date when the SUM of number is 6 and date > '2010-01-04'

I want return the date when the addition of the field number is equal to 6 (after a specific date, 2010-01-04 in this example). Example : my query should return 2010-01-07 because 2 in 2010-01-05 1 in 2010-01-06 3 in 2010-01-07

I've used this query until now, on MySQL Server:

```
select date 
    from 
      (select date, @n:=@n+total total 
          from 
            (select date, sum(number) total 
                from MyTable 
              where date > '2010-01-04' 
              group by date 
              order by date 
            ) t 
           cross join 
            (select @n:=0) n 
      ) tt 
   where total = 6
```

Now, we have only one server, on SQL Server and i have some problems for use this query on SQL Server.

Comment: you cannot use this query on sql server.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you an use this:

```
with calc as 
(
    select top 100 percent
                t1.id, t1.dt, SUM(t2.num) acm
    from        MyTable t1
    inner join  MyTable t2 on t1.id >= t2.id
    group by    t1.id, t1.dt
    order by    t1.id
)
select top 1 id, dt as Date, Acm
from   calc
where  Acm >= 6;
```

The result:

```
|id|Date               |Acm|
|-:|:------------------|--:|
| 5|06/01/2010 00:00:00|  6|
```

Another approach:

```
with calc2 as
(
    select id, dt, sum(num) over (order by dt) acm
    from @csum
)
select top 1 id, dt as Date, Acm
from   calc2
where  Acm >= 6;
```

Check it *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=0e8d0f7b41639a31f5359435d4261f4b)*

**Update**

If you need a reset point each time cumulative sum reaches 6, it's a bit more complicated.

```
with calc2 as
(
    select id, dt, num,
           sum(num) over (order by dt) acm, 
           sum(num) over (order by dt) / 6 reset
    from @csum
)
select id, dt as Date
from   @csum
where  id in (select min(id) from calc2 t2 where reset > 0 group by reset);
```

First CTE set a reset point each time cumulative sum reach 6. (keep in mind that it reset when SUM() = 6)

Second query returns first row of each 'reset' partition.

```
(select min(id) from calc2 t2 where reset > 0 group by reset)
```

Try *dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=b24169d02d0849560861951e9b332af3)*

Comment: Thank you!! it work.

i've add the field date in my query:

with calc as 
(
    select top 100 percent
                t1.id, t1.date, SUM(t2.num) acm
    from        mytable t1
    inner join  mytable t2 on t1.id >= t2.id
    where t2.date > '2017-02-24'
 group by    t1.id, t1.date
 order by    t1.id
)
select top 1 id, date as Date, Acm
from   calc
where  Acm >= 4
AND date > '2017-02-24';

Do you have an idea for return all dates each acm = 6? with start date is the date returned precedently

Comment: Do you mean: each time it reaches 6, reset to 0?

Comment: i've tested your code updated, with my datas. The first date returned is wrong but all the date after the first is correct.

Comment: by using the query inside calc2, you can see what's happening. @Pierre001

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this:

```
WITH
-- input, don't use in real query
input(id,the_date,the_number) AS (
          SELECT 1,DATE '2010-01-02',0
UNION ALL SELECT 2,DATE '2010-01-03',3
UNION ALL SELECT 3,DATE '2010-01-04',0
UNION ALL SELECT 4,DATE '2010-01-05',2
UNION ALL SELECT 5,DATE '2010-01-06',1
UNION ALL SELECT 6,DATE '2010-01-07',3
)
-- end of input, start "real" WITH clause here
,
run_sum AS (
SELECT
  *
, SUM(the_number) OVER(ORDER BY id) AS the_sum
FROM input
WHERE the_date > '2010-01-04'
)
-- the above returns:
-- SELECT * FROM run_sum;
-- id|the_date  |the_number|the_sum
--  4|2010-01-05|         2|      2
--  5|2010-01-06|         1|      3
--  6|2010-01-07|         3|      6
SELECT
  the_date
FROM run_sum
WHERE the_sum = 6
;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have MSSQL 2012 you can try this:

```
SELECT DATE 
    FROM 
      (SELECT DATE, SUM(TOTAL) OVER (ORDER BY DATE ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS TOTAL
          FROM 
            (SELECT DATE, SUM(NUMBER) TOTAL 
                FROM MYTABLE
              WHERE DATE > CONVERT(DATE, '2010-01-04',121) 
              GROUP BY DATE               
            ) T         
      ) TT 
   WHERE TOTAL = 6
```